# Is there a way I can exclude non repeating numbers in my array without creating another array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing, unique

I need to create an output that takes numbers from two arrays : `a` and `b`; and prints the unique ones out but only once. so for example if had

```
int[] a = { 4,3,4,3,6,7,4,8,2,9 };
int[] b = { 2,3,6,8,1,5 };`
```

the output should be `7, 4, 9` 
NOT `4, 4, 7, 4, 9`

In the task, it directly says: "Do not create any auxiliary arrays, collections or Strings. Do not use any classes from packages other than the standard java.lang. The arrays cannot be modified (in particular, they cannot be sorted). The order of printed values is irrelevant."

I have 90% of it, I just cant get the a array to not repeat numbers

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[]{1,2,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,123};
        int[] b = new int[]{2,1,3,6,4,5,8,9,12};



        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
         int count =0;
         for (int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
         {
            if(b[j]==a[i])count++;
         }
          if (count==0) System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

I'd expect `7 123`.
In actuality it prints `7 7 123`.
I know it has to be something crazy simple, but I'm just a beginner and can't yet wrap my head around it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Step through with the debugger, or just play computer with paper/pen[cil].

Comment: You don't currently have any logic for de-duping within a *single* array. There are multiple ways this could be handled.

Comment: This is literally what is on the task: "Write a program which denes two arrays of ints and prints all elements of the
rst array which do not appear in the second, but each value once only, without
repetitions.
For example for arrays
int[] arr = { 4,3,4,3,6,7,4,8,2,9 };
int[] brr = { 2,3,6,8,1,5 };
the result could be (the order of printed values is irrelevant):
7 4 9
Do not create any auxiliary arrays, collections or Strings. Do not use any classes
from packages other than the standard java.lang. The arrays cannot be modied (in
particular, they cannot be sorted)."

Comment: @monoxide When you're printing the unique element from the first array, suppose take 4 for example, 4 is repeated 3 times in the arr, so you check count == 0 and print the value because 4 is not present in the second array, but also verify if you have already used the number just by traversing the arr from current index -1 to 0, if this is the first occurrence then print it, if it's not the first occurrence then you've already printed the number. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the explanation along with the solution! @Juseeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code, you are checking if the current number is unique and printing it, but not checking for, if the number already has been used.
As we cannot use any additional data structure or modify existing contents, this is one way we can avoid printing the number already used.

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] a = new int[]{1,2,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,123};
            int[] b = new int[]{2,1,3,6,4,5,8,9,12};



            for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
             int count =0;
             for (int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
             {
                if(b[j]==a[i])count++;
             }
              if (count==0 && !visitedPreviously(i-1, a[i], arr)) System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
            }
        }

    private boolean visitedPreviously(int index, int val, int[] arr){
         while(index >= 0){
              if(val == arr[index]){
                 return true; 
              }
           index--;
         }
      return false;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Your `isRepeatingNumber` method is broken in at least 2 ways.

Comment: @AndyTurner Check it now, I have fixed it.

Comment: Dumping code without explanation does not make a good answer. You need to explain how what you are doing differs from what OP originally tried, why OP's approach doesn't work etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner I explained my approach in the above comments, I didn't want to duplicate my comments

Comment: comments are transient: they may be deleted at any time. Your answer needs to contain all the information so it can stand by itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner Accepted and added my explanation.

Comment: Threw an error, changed arr to a in: if (count==0 && !visitedPreviously(i-1, a[i], a)) System.out.print(a[i] + " "); but otherwise works perfectly. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to find unique elements:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 123};
int[] b = new int[]{2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12};

Stream<Integer> aStream = Arrays.stream(a).boxed();
Stream<Integer> bStream = Arrays.stream(b).boxed();

Set<Integer> intersection = aStream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
intersection.retainAll(bStream.collect(Collectors.toSet()));

Set<Integer> unique = Stream.concat(aStream, bStream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
unique.removeAll(intersection);

System.out.println(unique);
```

The result will be:

```
[7, 123]
```